# How to specify Delphi interface GUID in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Enterprise Architect code generation feature to export my models to Delphi code. Is there a way to specify interface GUIDs in EA so that interfaces are completely defined in the output code?

Example:

```
ILogger = interface
  procedure Log(AMessage: ILoggerMessage);
end;
```

should be

```
ILogger = interface
['{16B77CF4-4219-412D-B1F3-20E29E2E9D9E}']
  procedure Log(AMessage: ILoggerMessage);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to ILogger TaggedValue *Attribute* with value containing GUID in form that Delphi likes:

```
Attribute=['{16B77CF4-4219-412D-B1F3-20E29E2E9D9E}']
```

then you should modify Code Generation Template *Class Body* and add

```
%classTag:"Attribute"%
```

as the second line (should be after %if elemType == "Interface"%) 
Now EA should properly generate code with GUID's.
EA imports it well but fails to generate properly.

This is a quick fix for interfaces only, it's been long time since I programmed in Delphi so I'm not sure if classes can have such attributes as well, therefore solution is limited to interfaces, for now :).

Answer (score 2):

No. Delphi has no idea whether you'll need a GUID or not, as not all interfaces have to have one. (Interfaces that aren't intended for COM and don't implement IDispatch, for instance.) The IDE can't read your mind (yet - maybe there's hope for the future ), and can't know what type of interface you're planning on creating.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that EA does not support interfaces as in COM programming. But, you can try use the template editing feature to change the way code is generated...